# Round to nearest 0.5, Not 0.0

Tags: javascript, math

How can you find the nearest nb.5 value?

Excluding .0 values,

Example,

```
round(1.0) = 1.5
round(1.99) = 1.5
round(2.0) = 2.5
```

Comment: Just curious, what about `round(-1)`?

Comment: Should follow same logic, -0.01 = -0.5, -0.99 = -0.5, -1.00 = -1.5, - etc :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add `0.5` to the value returned by [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor):

```js
const round = (number) => Math.floor(number) + 0.5

console.log(round(1.0))
console.log(round(1.99))
console.log(round(2.0))
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, completely escaped me to do that.. 
I'm unsure which answer came first, but yours seem most elaborate, will accept when i am allowed to.

Comment: @user2267175 I answered 10 seconds earlier because IEatBagels was busy eating bagels

Comment: @adiga It seems this will be my downfall

Answer (score 4):

`Math.floor(value) + 0.5` should do it.

Also, you should clarify your specifications... Because the nearest 0.5 value of 2 is 1.5 AND 2.5, they both are at the same "distance".

I understand that your example deals with this scenario by going to the nearest upper 0.5 value, but is this really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function round(num) {
    return Math.round((num % 10)) + 0.5
}

console.log(round(1));
console.log(round(1.99));
console.log(round(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result ,use below option using Math.trunc - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc

```js
let round = (val) => Math.trunc(val) + 0.5
console.log(round(1.99))
console.log(round(1))
console.log(round(2))
```